# Dagger injected class keeps being null with Dagger

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, dagger

I'm trying to inject an instance of `CacheManager` into `GetTodoRepository` which Dagger is probably successfull with doing since I'm not getting any dagger related errors. But when using `cacheManager` in `GetTodoRepository` I get a NullPointerException

```
public class GetTodoRepository {

    @Inject
    public CacheManager cacheManager;

    public RetrofitService retrofitService;
    private ResultListener listener;

    public GetTodoRepository(@NonNull ResultListener listener) {
        this.retrofitService = new RetrofitService();
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}

@Module
public class AppModule {

    private Application application;

    public AppModule(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Context providesApplicationContext() {
        return application.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public CacheManager provideCacheManager(Context Context) {
        return new CacheManager(Context);
    }

}



@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface TodoComponents {
    void inject(MainViewModel mainViewModel);
    void inject(CacheManager cacheManager);
    void inject(GetTodoRepository getTodoRepository);
    void inject(PostTodoRepository postTodoRepository);
}
```

Comment: What's your component looks like?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman The component class is now visible in the question

Comment: You have to **inject** `GetTodoRepository` to dagger. Have you done this?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I have exactly only done what I have pasted. By injecting to dagger what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) Setup Dagger (Component) in Application class**

```
public class TodoApplication extends Application {

private static AppComponent components;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    components = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(this))
            .build();
}


public static AppComponent getAppComponent() {
    return components;
}
```

}

**2) Call the `Component` object from `Application` class in the injection target class**

```
public GetTodoRepository(@NonNull ResultListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
    TodoApplication.getAppComponent().inject(this);
}
```